# Creating a standalone exe file from sictus prolog pl file windows

Tags: windows, dll, compilation, prolog, sicstus-prolog

I have a sictus prolog file (.pl-file) that I would like to export as an exe-file to run on another computer.

Searching through SICS documentation and playing around with spld gave me an exe file which didn't work on antoher computer(running windows xp x86).

I'm using Sicstus on Windows 7 professional(x64) and would like to have a simple step by step instruction on how to create a standalone exe that will run on x86 and x64 windows from a sicstus prolog file.

Something like:

1: Compile pl-file using ...

2: ...

Is this possible?

PS assume that I know nothing about dependencies and dll:s
PPS the code uses one module

```
:- use_module(library(sets)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you to Gilles solution, which would work if I hadn't included any of sicstus built in libraries.

After e-mailing SICS they gave me the answer, which I would have posted here if I hadn't encountered this error:

[Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127641/your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code)

Instead I downloaded [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/), used it to convert my markdown into HTML and posted the solution [here](http://www.csc.kth.se/~jwikst/sicstus_standalone.html).

If anyone could help me correct my markdown, please answer [the question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127641/your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code) and I'll post the answer here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think GNU Prolog is a compiler that can in principle do this for you:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gprolog/